# Redirecting server output to client?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am working on a webapp in java and the app has two textareas, one for writing java code and another for execution of code.so how can i redirect the server output to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you're executing the code, assuming that you're using a Process object, just capture all lines from the output and error streams, then when the process closes, send the output to the client.

Comment: Thank you, I am using Processbuilder to create process object. I want the output to be executed to the client end so that if the interaction needed  the programmer can input the required fields at execution.

Comment: if I am right of what you mean then then you have to encapsulate the user java code in an applet to execute it on client side.

Comment: I do want the code to be compiled and executed at the server side and the execution should be visible to client.

Comment: I'm not really sure about how to do that, you could have a websocket thing running in the background after the servlet sends the response to forward all output to the client via a websocket or something